# Replacing text on div

Tags: jquery

I have a form that if I select certain values from a `<select>` and `<input>`, the jquery goes in action.

I have the following div:

```html
<div class="alert alert-info"  role="alert">
    <div id="holders_1_contracts">
        Contratos deste Titular: &nbsp; <i class="fal fa-spinner fa-spin-2x"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

If the `<select id="holders_1_partner_type_id">` changed, this enter in action:

```
$('#holders_1_partner_type_id').change(function()
{
    $("#holders_1_contracts").replaceWith('Contratos deste Titular: &nbsp; <i class="fal fa-spinner fa-spin-2x"></i>');
});
```

If the `<input id="holders_1_partner_nr"`, changes, this enter in action:

```
$('#holders_1_partner_nr').change(function()
{
    let partner_type_id = $("#holders_1_partner_type_id").val();
    let partner_nr = $("#holders_1_partner_nr").val();

    switch(partner_type_id) {
        case '2':
            $.ajax({
                url: '...',
                type: 'get',
                data: {
                ..
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    let data = JSON.parse(response);

                    if (data.success !== false) {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'success',
                            title: 'OCC Encontrado!',
                            text: 'Os campos foram pré-preenchidos. Valide os dados antes de avançar.',
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            allowOutsideClick: true,
                        });

                        $("#holders_1_contracts").replaceWith(data.contracts);

                    } else {
                        Swal.fire({
                            ...
                        });
                    }
                },
            });
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Basically, if the user enters the `holders_1_partner_nr` (number), the application loads the contract numbers from the database. If the `holders_1_partner_type_id` changes, the jquery should replace all loaded contracts with a text and a spinner.

The fact is, this code only works 1 time, If I load the contracts 1 time.

What am I doing wrong? My jquery/js skills aren't really the best.

Regards and Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does replacing the content maybe remove the event listeners?

Comment: hI @NicoHaase, I don't have much experiencing with jquery, but I placed console.log() inside the events to check if they are executing and I can see them on console tab from chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each case, you're replacing/removing the element the event lister is attached to.

Please change:

```
.replaceWith( ..... );
```

To:

```
.html( ..... );
```

Comment: Thanks! Misunderstood the ```replaceWith``` method. Really need to take a front-end course, at least a basic one. Have a good day!